# Sum values ​from the same ID respecting filters

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that, through some relationships, shows me several rows for a single ID_PROD, and does a multiplication of the THEORETICAL_WEIGHT and REAL_WEIGHT columns. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  D.ID_STORAGE,
  D.QUIN, 
  A.ID_PROD AS ID_PROD_FULL,
  SUBSTR(A.ID_PROD, 1, 4) AS ID_PROD,
  B.PROD_GROUP,
  A.REAL_WEIGHT,
  C.VALK,
  C.REV,
  C.STORAGE_TYPE,
  B.THEORETICAL_WEIGHT,
  B.THEORETICAL_WEIGHT * A.REAL_WEIGHT AS FINAL_WEIGHT
FROM 
  Table_a A,
  Table_b B,
  Table_c C,
  Table_d D
WHERE 
  C.STORAGE_TYPE = D.STORAGE_TYPE
  AND C.ID_STORAGE = D.ID_STORAGE
  AND C.ID_LINE = D.ID_LINE
  AND A.ID_PROD = C.ID_PROD
  AND B.ID_PROD = C.ID_PROD
  AND B.ID_PROD = A.ID_PROD
  AND A.NRT = C.NRT;
```

This query gives me results like this:

```
ID_STORAGE | QUIN | ID_PROD_FULL | ID_PROD | PROD_GROUP | REAL_WEIGHT | VALK | REV | STORAGE_TYPE | THEORETICAL_WEIGHT | FINAL_WEIGHT  |
HESZ       |   Z  |   P001-IUU   |   P001  |      NM    |      0,34   |   J  |   X |       KO     |           3        |       1,02    |
HESZ       |   Z  |   P001-IUU   |   P001  |      TT    |      0,22   |   J  |   X |       KO     |           3        |       0,66    |
HESZ       |   Z  |   P002-IUY   |   P002  |      NM    |      0,11   |   J  |   X |       TO     |           5        |       0,55    |
FRES       |   Z  |   P002-IUY   |   P002  |      NM    |      0,45   |   J  |   X |       KO     |           5        |       2,25    |
FRES       |   Z  |   P002-ICX   |   P002  |      BV    |      0,77   |   J  |   Y |       WE     |           5        |       1,54    |
```

I'm trying, but I'm not able to rearrange this query so that each PROD_ID appears **only once**, together with REAL_WEIGHT (sum of all the REAL_WEIGHT of that same PROD_ID), THEORETICAL_WEIGHT (unique theoretical weight for each PROD_ID) and FINAL_WEIGHT (REAL_WEIGHT * THEORETICAL_WEIGHT). I want this calculation to be done only for the rows where the filters below match:

- STORAGE_TYPE = KO, TO, Z
- PROD_GROUP = NM, Z, S
- C.VALK = J, C, D, E
- ID_STORAGE = HESZ, FRES
- D.QUIN = Z, K
- C.REV = X, Y, H

Based on the example table I showed above, the expected result would be something like this:

```
ID_PROD  | REAL_WEIGHT | THEORETICAL_WEIGHT | FINAL_WEIGHT |
   P001  |    0,34     |        3           |      1,02    |
   P002  |    0,56     |        5           |      2,8     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(A.ID_PROD, 1, 4) AS ID_PROD,
  SUM(A.REAL_WEIGHT) REAL_WEIGHT,
  B.THEORETICAL_WEIGHT,
  SUM(B.THEORETICAL_WEIGHT * A.REAL_WEIGHT) AS FINAL_WEIGHT
FROM 
  Table_a A,
  Table_b B,
  Table_c C,
  Table_d D
WHERE 
  C.STORAGE_TYPE = D.STORAGE_TYPE
  AND C.ID_STORAGE = D.ID_STORAGE
  AND C.ID_LINE = D.ID_LINE
  AND A.ID_PROD = C.ID_PROD
  AND B.ID_PROD = C.ID_PROD
  AND B.ID_PROD = A.ID_PROD
  AND A.NRT = C.NRT
  AND D.STORAGE_TYPE IN ('KO', 'TO', 'Z')
  AND B.PROD_GROUP IN ('NM', 'Z', 'S')
  AND C.VALK IN ('J', 'C', 'D', 'E')
  AND D.ID_STORAGE IN ('HESZ', 'FRES')
  AND D.QUIN IN ('Z', 'K')
  AND C.REV IN ('X', 'Y', 'H')
GROUP BY SUBSTR(A.ID_PROD, 1, 4), B.THEORETICAL_WEIGHT
```